# webview does not show all content

Tags: android, android-webview

I need to load url in webView - http://intor.club/files/comments.php?serial=56
I can not see in the webView that I see in the browser. Mobile browser works. 
JavaScript is on. Help me! Thank you!

```
mWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("http://intor.club/files/comments.php?serial=56");
```

Comment: did you show it in fragment

Comment: yes i did, i can see other url's in my webview but it is not (http://intor.club/files/comments.php?serial=56)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure you xml file you showing your webview like that 
width fill parent and height also

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

don't forget your internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

it should work know

i test it myself

when i comment javascript enable i got this

```
 //wbeview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

[image]

when i enable java Script i get this (there are no comment in this thread)

i see you want access comment , may be you not authorized to access it.

Things you should try :-

1- try connect  your facebook or any other connection to this site and access this link again .

2- try connect to main Page it will work "http://intor.club/ "

[image]

Comment: i can see other url's in my webview but it is not (http://intor.club/files/comments.php?serial=56) Please, try yourself load this url...

Comment: its not about android code , this code should display any web site , its about the site , when your app request to preview this site its return this message , There are not comment in this thread , so check the site api